# How to remove None values

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a spark dataframe with a **None** value on first row.

df_spark.show()

[image]

I created the above dataframe initailly in pandas then converted to a spark dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'rid': ['A', 'B', 'C'],
        'num': [None, 8, 9],
        'availability_percent': [56, 69, 70],
        'availability_spaces': [7, 6, 5]
    }
)
```

Then:

`df_spark = spark.createDataFrame(df)`

When i do `df_spark.filter(df_spark.num.isNotNull()).show()`

i get the same dataframe above, meaning my row with Nan values was not remove. What i did wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a check for `isNan` to cover the case of `NAN` values

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import isnan

df_spark.filter(~isnan(df_spark.num) & df_spark.num.isNotNull()).show()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the lines containing null values with the following instruction :

```py
df.na.drop().show(false)
```

Comment: Hi, thank you. As i know with df.na.drop() you drop the rows containing any null or NaN values. but with filter() you can choose only a specific column you want for those null values to be droped.